# Creating a Connect 4 game in python but don't know where to begin with a win condition

Tags: python

I'm still pretty green working with python but I figured making my own game from scratch with what I know would be good practice. I've got this connect four game together and it works in so far as switching between players and 'dropping' their respective pieces. Now I need a win condition, though honestly, I don't know where to start. I'd prefer some guidance as opposed to straight code for the sake of learning, but of course, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks. Quick note, the current while loop is simply for debugging. I was thinking about setting a variable 'winner' to False and doing the loop 'while winner == False:' and have the win condition set this variable to True.

```
board = [] #List for holding the board

for x in range(6):
    board.append(["O"] * 7) #builds 7 x 6 board (rows x columns)

#function for printing the board
def print_board(board):  
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

print 'Welcome to Connect Four'

player_one = raw_input('Player 1. Enter your name: ')
player_two = raw_input('Player 2. Enter your name: ') #Gets players names

print '%s vs. %s' % (player_one, player_two)
print '--------------'
print print_board(board)
print 'Player 1 is Red(R) and Player 2 is Black(B)'
print 'Let\'s play!!' # Game's 'Opening'

turn = 0 #Keeps track of turn


while turn < 6: #debugging purposes

if turn % 2 == 0: #Determines whose turn it is by checking for even or odd turn 

    print '%s. Choose a column to drop your chip' % (player_one)
    one_choice = int(raw_input('Column: ')) #Determines what column player will drop chip

   #Checks for 'empty slot' from bottom up and fills it with players 'chip'

    if (board[5][one_choice - 1] == 'O'):             
        board[5][one_choice - 1] = 'R'
        print_board(board)
        turn += 1

    elif(board[4][one_choice - 1] == 'O'):
        board[4][one_choice - 1] = 'R'
        print_board(board)
        turn += 1

    elif(board[3][one_choice - 1] == 'O'):
        board[3][one_choice - 1] = 'R'
        print_board(board)
        turn += 1

    elif (board[2][one_choice - 1] == 'O'):
        board[2][one_choice - 1] = 'R'
        print_board(board)
        turn += 1

    elif (board[1][one_choice - 1] == 'O'):
        board[1][one_choice - 1] = 'R'
        print_board(board)
        turn += 1

    elif (board[0][one_choice - 1] == 'O'):
        board[0][one_choice - 1] = 'R'
        print_board(board)
        turn += 1

    else:
        print "Column is full!!"      
else:         

    #Same as above for player 2
    print '%s. Choose a column to drop your chip' % (player_two)
    one_choice = int(raw_input('Column: '))

    if (board[5][one_choice - 1] == 'O'):
        board[5][one_choice - 1] = 'B'
        print_board(board)
        turn += 1

    elif(board[4][one_choice - 1] == 'O'):
        board[4][one_choice - 1] = 'B'
        print_board(board)
        turn += 1

    elif(board[3][one_choice - 1] == 'O'):
        board[3][one_choice - 1] = 'B'
        print_board(board)
        turn += 1

    elif (board[2][one_choice - 1] == 'O'):
        board[2][one_choice - 1] = 'B'
        print_board(board)
        turn += 1

    elif (board[1][one_choice - 1] == 'O'):
        board[1][one_choice - 1] = 'B'
        print_board(board)
        turn += 1

    elif (board[0][one_choice - 1] == 'O'):
        board[0][one_choice - 1] = 'B'
        print_board(board)
        turn += 1

    else:
        print "Column is full!!"

 #Gets me out of loop for debugging
if turn == 6:
    print 'Game Over man!'
```

Comment: *"I don't know where to start"* - then you're not ready to ask a question here.

Comment: Sorry. I did do research though and everything I found didn't seem to coincide with the board type that I created. This may be because i'm still learning to read other people's code. I'll try to be more thorough next time before posting my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a 7x6 board, and you need to see if a line of 4 adjacent or diagonal spaces contain the same symbol.  This 7x6 board is being stored in a two dimensional array.

For a piece placed in the board, you'll have 4 sets of checks you must do to see if it was a winning piece:

1. Check to the left/right for 3 of your pieces.
2. Check to the upper left/lower right for 3 of your pieces.
3. Check to the lower left/upper right for 3 of your pieces.
4. Check above and below for 3 of your pieces.

If we consider X and Y your current board coordinate, wherever I place a piece, these checks correspond to:

1. X increases/decreases, Y is constant.
2. As X increases, Y decreases, and vice versa.
3. As X increases, Y increases, and vice versa.
4. X is constant, Y increases/decreases.

You should do a lazy check, checking each direction and going the other way as soon as you find something that isn't your piece.  If both directions are complete and your total pieces are not 4, that wasn't a winning vector and go on to the next check.

EDIT: Formatting and clarity.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it. Sorry if it doesn't seem like I did any research on the matter but everything I found on 'connect four win conditions' didn't seem to coincide with the way I built my board. Though that may be simply because i'm still learning to read other people's code. But again thanks, and thanks for the direction as opposed to an answer. Hopefully i'll be fishing in no time lol.

Comment: You got it. Thanks again. I've got a semi working win function now. Just trying to figure out how to get it to stay inside the indices. I'm getting there though.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a disjoint sets problem but your graph is so small that it would probably be easier to just check all four directions each time like @John Rodgers was talking about. Disjoint sets would probably be a useful thing to learn though. Here's a wikipedia page if you just want to read about it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure